# google analytics meta tag verification for segment.io integration

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, segment-io

So the segment.io docs say here https://segment.io/docs/integrations/google-analytics#webmaster-tools that I "need to switch to the Meta tags verification option" to verify ga in conjunction w webmaster tools.

That led me to instructions here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35659?hl=en that seem to be totally clear and simple. Big problem...google has since changed their webmaster tool interface and the meta tag verification id info is nowhere to be found...

The instructions (from Google) say to click the "Verify this site" option on the "Manage Site" menu of the Webmaster Tools homepage. Well, I see the "Manage Site" menu but the only options are: Add or remove users, Google Analytics property, and Delete site. Well, Google Analytics property seems to fit this criteria well enough, but that page also says nothing about meta tag verification.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Google has not changed their interface, it's just that as long as your site is already verified you cannot change the verification method. The option should re-appear as soon as Google can longer determine that the page is actually yours (i.e. if you remove whatever verification is currently in place - i assume at the moment you verified via the GA account).

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff. So I assume that means that if I am moving to segment.io we will not lose the Google Analytics <> Webmaster Tools connection? Also, maybe you can move your comment to an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while Eike Pierstorff answer in comment is correct, it's pretty easy to find your verification code simply by adding anoter domain to verify - you could go with example.com just to get the code on verification step.

You could also remove your domain from GWT and add it once again - then you'd get the code but i'm not sure if you'll have all the historical data.